# Powershell not creating registry key when script is run

Tags: powershell, registry

I am currently creating a powershell script in which the technicians can run to help apply various registry edits to create certain PCs which have automatic logins. However, whenever I run my script the powershell has no issue when changing values with pre-existing keys, yet it will not create keys when using the "new-item" command. I was wondering whether anyone would have any idea as to why this would not create the registry key given that I receive no errors when run.

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" –Name AutoAdminLogon -Value 1
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name DefaultUserName -Value domain\TEST
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name DefaultPassword -Value TEST123
Test-Path –Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ForceAutoLogon"
if ( -Not (Test-Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"))
{
New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name ForceAutoLogon  -Value 1
}
```

Comment: Are you running the script with elevated permissions?

Comment: My windows account is an administrator account, and I have also tried running the same syntax with powershell as Administrator and it still does not apply any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Test-Path` is not designed for registy values. What you can do it use a Try/Catch block. You also need to Get/Set the itemPropery.

```
$Path = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"
Try {
    Get-ItemProperty -Path $Path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ForceAutoLogon -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name ForceAutoLogon -Value 1
} Catch {
    New-ItemProperty -Path $Path -Name ForceAutoLogon -Value 1
}
```

If the `Get-ItemProperty` fails the the key must not exist. Then we can create it! If `Get-ItemProperty` succeeds then we can ensure the value is set properly. I might be using the registry keywords wrong but let the code speak for itself.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your suggestion. I have just tried this and it still does not make any difference. I have actually just attempted running 'New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" -Name ForceAutoLogon -Value 1' by itself and it still doesn't create anything.

Comment: @Josh1893 looking at this more now. I've been editing like a madman

Comment: Just tried it and seems to be working fine now, thank you so much! Was there anything wrong with my New-Item syntax? Because I don't understand how running that wouldn't create the registry key.

Comment: @Josh1893 please look at my updated answer. I'm sure you accepted my answer incorrectly. This should be correct.

Comment: Well the previous answer seemed to work so I don't think it was incorrect. Can this be applied to other types of Reg keys such as REG_DWORDS?

Comment: This logic should be applicable to all key types yes. Just make sure you set the `Value` appropriately for the key in question.